# Google programmable search bar not display unless i press reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

So im very new to google products. Im just learning my way around adSense, analytics and search bar.

Im using a react based project.
I have added the code to the body as requested in public html and have added the search bar to my site.

```
    <!-- <script 
     async 
     src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=cxxxx" 
     ></script> -->
```

But i cant grt it to stabilise. I have to keep reloading and i have no control over the size

Reloading
Using react versions.
Lots of ggoogle